# How do I refer to nameless objects by their properties?

Tags: c#, variables, object

How can I refer to nameless objects?
For a game, if I'm making a square grid and using something like

```
for (int X =0; X <= 10; X++)
{
    for(int Y =0; Y <= 10; Y++)
    {
        new Cell(X, Y);
    }
}
```

I'm going to have 100 cells with no name. How do I modify or check them afterwards, perhaps referring to them by their coords, such as

```
ThisCell.DoSomething();
```

referring to the cell by its coords or something

Halp. I can't just have 1000 or more cells each with their own little pet name to call on. There's got to be a way to check, for examples, the neighbors of something by something's coords WITHOUT MAKING NEW CELLS...

Basically the problem I'm having is that for each neighbor check, for example, I'm creating new, default cells which return the wrong values.

If any of you could, for example, give me a good function which checks the `boolean` `IsWalkable` of its upward neighbor... I would appreciate it tremendously

Comment: Put them in a (probably multidimensional) array. If you don't store the reference, then you can't refer to them again.

Comment: As @Matt says, if you don't keep a reference to them, you can't get them again.  But not only that, as soon as you move beyond the `new Cell()` line, they'll become available for garbage collection and potentially won't even exist anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create an array of your type `Cell`:

```
Cell[,] myCells = new Cell[10,10]
```

change `new Cell(X, Y);` to `myCells[X,Y] = new Cell();`

From there you can always refer to any cell:
`myCells[1,2].DoSomething()`;

Answer (score 1):

Create an array then store your cells in it

```
Cell[,] cells = new Cell[10,10];
for (int X =0; X <= 10; X++)
{
    for(int Y =0; Y <= 10; Y++)
    {
        cells[X,Y] = new Cell(X, Y);
    }
}
```

To retrieve a cell late, you just use it's x and y coordinates to index the array:

```
Cell someCell = cells[5,5];   // for example
```

It's easy to find neighbors by just manipulating the coordinates. For example, if each cell also has it's own X and Y coordinates (which your constructor parameters suggest) you could do something like:

```
Cell cellAboveMe = cells[someCell.X, someCell.Y - 1];
```

Although note that you'll want to include boundary checking (if `Y==0` then there is no cell above this cell)

This is pretty fundamental stuff, so you'll want to read up on how arrays work.  See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

For example.

Comment: Cell someCell = cells[5,5];
That's what I'm saying, doesn't this clone the cell or create a new object?

Comment: @AlexMitan: Assuming `Cell` is a reference type (a class) and not a value type (a struct), no. It doesn't clone it and it doesn't create a new object. For your OutOfRange exception, you are passing an index to an array that is out-of-range.

Comment: 'code'
Cell[,] TestField = new Cell[9, 9];

            for (int cX = 0; cX < 8; cX++)
            {
                for (int cY = 0; cY < 8; cY++)
                {
                    TestField[cX,cY] = new Cell(cX,cY);
                }
            }
'code'

returns an OutOfRange as well...

Comment: @AlexMitan: No it doesn't (see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zr5QUA). There is no way that code gives you an `OutOfRangeException`. If you are getting an exception from that, then you have something else going on that you are not telling us. Perhaps it's from the constructor for `Cell` (you never shared that code). Also note, you should be looping `< 9` if you want to fill the whole array, you are missing the last column and the last row.